# Best practice to store single value in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I have a Lambda that is generating and returning a value. This value can expire. Therefore I need to check the values validity before returning.
As generating is quite expensive (taken from another service) I'd like to store the value somehow.

What is the best practice for storing those 2 values (timestamp and a corresponding value)?

- DynamoDB, but using a database service for 2 values seems to be a lot of overhead. There will never be more items; The same entry will only get updated.
- I thought about S3, but this would also imply creating a S3-Bucket and storing one object containing the information, only for this 2 values (but probably the most "lean" way?)
- Would love to update Lambdas configuration in order to update the environment variables (but even if this is possible, its probably no best practice?! Also not sure about inconsistencies with Lambda runtimes...)

Whats best practice here? Whats the way to go in terms of performance?

Comment: Have you looked at SQS (https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/)?

Comment: I'd use DynamoDB. The cost would be minimal for this use case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Use [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/).** There is no overhead for "running a database" -- it is a fully-managed service. You pay only for storage and provisioned capacity. It sounds like your use-case would fit within the [Free Usage Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/).

Alternatively, you could use **API Gateway** with a cache setting so that it doesn't even call the Lambda function unless a timeout has passsed.

Comment: Could you say why DynamoDB might be preferred over Parameter Store?

Comment: Frankly, these days I'd use Parameter Store before DynamoDB. If high throughput is required, there are "Advanced Parameters" that offer 1000 API calls per second.

Answer (score 12):

You could consider [AWS Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html)

> AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store provides secure, hierarchical
>   storage for configuration data management and secrets management. You
>   can store data such as passwords, database strings, and license codes
>   as parameter values. You can store values as plain text or encrypted
>   data. You can then reference values by using the unique name that you
>   specified when you created the parameter. Highly scalable, available,
>   and durable, Parameter Store is backed by the AWS Cloud. Parameter
>   Store is offered at no additional charge.

Comment: Could you say why Parameter Store might be preferred over DynamoDB?

Comment: SSM is intended for parameters that don't change very often, while DynamoDB is designed for online processing. Be aware that SSM allows only 40 requests per second by default: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ssm.html#limits_ssm

Comment: It's likely you will hit the limit, so mongo/DynamoDB should be used IMO.

Comment: Since 2019 you can get 1000 calls per second on a parameter.

Answer (score -3):

For cases like this I would use some fast in-memory data store, like Redis or Memcached:

- https://redis.io/
- https://memcached.org/

And luckily there is Amazon ElastiCache:

- https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/

which is managed Redis and Memcached, but you don't need to use it for your use case - you could easily use Redis on your own EC2, or you could use an external service like Compose that also supports instances inside of Amazon data centers:

- https://www.compose.com/

Lots of ways to use it but I would certainly use Redis, especially for simple cases like this.

Comment: Why would use a full elasticache to store 2 pieces of data?  How would in-memory work when the Lambda went away?

Comment: This will cost more than the Lambda itself.

Answer (score -4):

Just set the environment variable with a value and a date.
Then check the date every time lambda is executed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateFunctionConfiguration.html

Comment: Could anyone comment on why this answer was downvoted?